# canvas..toDataURL and upload it

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

Am working on converting canvas to image and upload it to server when the user submit the form.
The image posted correctly but it appears empty in the server.

Here is my code, (Am using phonegap)
`.drawImage ()`is in the main.js .. but `canvas..toDataURL`is in a script in the html

```
 <script>

 function insert()
 {
var img = document.getElementById("myCanvas")[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg");
$.ajax({
type: "POST",

url: "http://*******************/create.php?title="+      ($("#myTitle").val())+"&description="
+$("#myDesc").val()+"&price="+$("#myPrice").val(),

data: {img: img},
success: function(data)
{
    alert("inserted");
}});

</script>
```

php

```
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Any idea ?

***EDIT !!!***

Finally it is UPLOADING!!!

Thanks to Jack Franzen for his suggestion.
I've changed the php code to

```
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = uniqid() . '.jpg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

and it is working as charm! :)

Comment: As you have found out, the JavaScript part is fine. For the PHP part, you could replace your implementation with a call to [PHP-FileUpload](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload), which includes [`DataUriUpload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda/src/DataUriUpload.php), documented [here](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/tree/023f812226673ac9e0696d8a3579bb7380606dda#data-uri-uploads). It takes care of everything, i.e. accepting one or multiple MIME types and mapping to extensions, choosing filenames, validating sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Know your problem! Your PHP code is looking for a "PNG", but your javascript is generating a "JPG"

Just switch toDataURL("image/jpeg") To toDataURL()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed the code as you suggested. Also I applied try () and catch (), the error that has been caught is ( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of null). It still appear empty.